# Inflating RadioGroup in Android-multiple radioButtons check at a time

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-inflate

I made a `RadioGroup` with a variable number of radioButtons. The problem is that many radiobuttons can be checked, it is not a single `RadioButton` checked in a `RadioGroup` (as I know) Where is my mistake? 
Here is my code :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionnaire_check_question, null);
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    for (int k = 0; k < answerValues.size(); k++) {
         View radioButtonView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_radio_button, null);
         RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioButtonView
                            .findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
         radioButton.setText(answerValues.get(k));
         radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView);
    }
questionBody.addView(view);
```

questionnaire_check_question.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#A4A7A6" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

check_radio_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
 >

</RadioButton>
```

drawable/checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_checkbox_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_checkbox_off" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

The radioGroup has a strange functionality..if I check the first RadioGroup, and then the second one, the first on become unchecked...after this, if I want to select again the first one, I can't do this..it doesn't check anymore.
Can anyone help me ? Any idea is welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution: the problem was that all buttons have the same ID. So I set a unique id for each radioButton.

Answer (score -2):

I am giving an example how this is done, you then modify your code accordingly.
In your xml, to add radio buttons, you need to define a layout like below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your Java File, do this:
i)Declare radio group and radiobutton like below -

```
 private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
  private RadioButton radioSexButton;
  private Button btn;
```

ii)Register your radiobutton and radiogroup with the xml layout like below -

```
radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
```

iii)Add onclicklistner on button like below -

```
btn.setOnClickListner(this);
```

iv)Implement OnClickListner interface and Override the unimplemented methods of OnClickListner interface

v) In the overrided method OnClick, code the following -

```
int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And this is how it is done..Hope this helps.